# How to split the path to get the directory in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to split the path of a file to get the directory name to check if the directory exists in the new location or not using shell script.

I tried using

```
cf=src/classes/CarExperience.cls
echo ${cf%/*} 
echo ${cf##/*/}
echo ${cf#/*/*/}
echo ${cf%/*}

echo $(dirname "$cf")
```

But none of these are giving me desired result

Desired result is get part after the src and check if that inner directory exists or not.
cf=src/classes/CarExperience.cls
directory_name=classes

Appreciate any help on this regard.

Comment: `cf="${cf#*/}; cf="${cf%/*}"` should do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```sh
full_dir=$(dirname "$cf")
last_dir=$(basename "$full_dir")
```

or in one shot

```sh
last_dir=$(basename "$(dirname "$cf")")
```

Yes, you want all those quotes.

With shell parameter expansion:

```sh
full_dir=${cf%/*}
last_dir=${full_dir##*/}
```

That one has to be done in 2 steps.

Comment: i was trying to figure out the one shot thing...thanks alot

Comment: @kumar : But don't forget that two child-processes are cretated for the "one-line" version, while no child process is needed in the version using parameter expansion. Depending on your concrete case, this might noticeably affect the execution time, if you do this inside a loop.

Comment: i am using it in inside the look and it is affecting the execution time.Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using *parameter expansion* as you try to do:

```
cf=src/classes/CarExperience.cls
cf=${cf#src/*} # become 'classes/CarExperience.cls'
echo ${cf%/*}  # become 'classes'
```

## Output

```
classes
```